# Need a replacement 42 ring for an Ultegra 9 speed triple

Tags: crankset

I am replacing my chainrings on a Shimano Ultegra triple crankset. It is 9 speed circa 2003. I can't find a replacement 42 ring as I don't think they make them any more. (I have the replacement 30 and 52 rings). What current 42 ultra ring will work with this 9 speed triple? Thanks

Comment: I have a similar question? I have 105. I'm looking to replace a 9-speed 42T aluminium chainring with a used 8-speed steel chainring I found. What new chainring could I use?

Comment: Take the old one off and visit your LBS.  42 tooth chainrings shouldn't be rare, but the combination of BCD and spider shape may limit your choices.  Do install a new chain at the same time.

Comment: @pdmclean your comment is a separate question completely - delete this one and ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar problem but with both the 42 and the 30T chain rings.
Bike shop told me they no longer have the Ultra 42 and got me an FSA 42 ring which works fine.
They were able to put on a Shimano SG 30T ring and if anything that sometimes hangs up even though there is a new chain put on. Still working on that one.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Internet search turned up this seller.  Looks pricey but has lots of options if you wanted to change your gearing as well.

- http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/chainrings.asp

Answer (score 0):

It has to be exactly a 42?
It is your middle
This is the Shimano part number for a 39 Y1LK98020 and lots of sources